# Another coredump issue in C

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, coredump

when I compile my code with
`g++ -g -o prueba prueba.cpp -lstdc++ -O3 -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7 -std=c++0x`

After debugging with `g++ -g prueba.cpp`, I got these:

```
prueba.cpp:24:6: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’
tm = std::stoi(string2);
     ^
prueba.cpp:34:7: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’
ler = std::stoi(string1);
      ^
prueba.cpp:77:8: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’
C[i]=std::stoi(string);
     ^
```

The way I declare `stoi` as `std::stoi` was based on [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

And the broken block is:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
if( B != NULL )
{
    for(i=0;i<div;i++)
    {
        a=B[i][0];
        b=B[i][1];
        std::cout<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\n";
        A[b][a]=A[b][a]+1;
        A[a][b]=A[a][b]+1;
    }   
    free(B);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////
```

which is given me the problem with segmentation fault. But I don't see what or where is the problem.

The files are:

LER https://app.box.com/s/oi52zw7j8w19txr4cau2pf4w3pzmcelm

REL https://app.box.com/s/bo2xwm2hviucx4jzarxv9ghg11j72goa

TM  https://app.box.com/s/ofmhsttqujor6di0tm89tiiikm3ou1xj

The full code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a,b,div,value,k,i,j,tm,ler;  
char string[256];
char string1[256];
char string2[256];

FILE *TM = fopen("TM","r");
if(TM == NULL)
{  
    printf("Can't open %s\n","TM");
    exit(1);
}
fscanf(TM,"%255s",string2);
tm = std::stoi(string2);
fclose(TM);

FILE *LER = fopen("LER","r");
if(LER == NULL)
{  
    printf("Can't open %s\n","LER");
    exit(1);
}
fscanf(LER,"%255s",string1);
ler = std::stoi(string1);
fclose(LER);

div=ler/2;

int **A;
A = (int **)malloc(tm*sizeof(int*));
for(j=0;j<tm;j++)
{
    A[j]=(int*)malloc(tm*sizeof(int));
}

int **B;
B = (int **)malloc(div*sizeof(int*));
for(j=0;j<div;j++)
{
    B[j]=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
}

int *C;
C = (int*) malloc(ler*sizeof(int));

if( A != NULL )
{
    for(i=0;i<tm;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<tm;j++)
        {
            A[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

FILE *stream = fopen("REL","r");
if(stream == NULL)
{  
    printf("Can't open %s\n","REL");
    exit(1);
}

for(i=0;i<ler;i++)
{
        fscanf(stream,"%255s",string);
        C[i]=std::stoi(string);
}
fclose(stream);

if( C != NULL )
{
    k=0;
    for(i=0;i<div;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            B[i][j]=C[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
    free(C);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////
if( B != NULL )
{
    for(i=0;i<div;i++)
    {
        a=B[i][0];
        b=B[i][1];
        std::cout<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\n";
        A[b][a]=A[b][a]+1;
        A[a][b]=A[a][b]+1;
    }   
    free(B);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////
for(i=0;i<tm;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<tm;j++)
    {
        cout<<A[i][j]; 
    }
    cout<<"\n"; 
}
free(A);
}
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger and find out exactly where it crashes - may also give you a clue on why. Other alternative is to add prints to narrow down the location.

Comment: Thank you @John3136 and I added prints to narrow it. The issued part is the first block of this post.

Comment: `stoi`  is operating as expected?

Comment: Do you have a guarantee that `A!=NULL` at that point (unlikely the source of issue but still you are checking for `B` why not checking for `A`)?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I use it to convert a number-string to number-number and when I print a matrix before the issued block.... yes, it works

Comment: @dvhh I just did it and still get the same. But, both matrices, A and B, are working well before that part

Comment: You should be able to narrow down to an actual line, not just a block. Might help if you specify your inputs too - if they are too big perhaps a malloc failed?

Comment: @John3136 How can I share that file? and yes... is a list of only numbers... almost 30k

Comment: @beginner and you have guarantees that `tm` >= any values in `C` ?

Comment: @dvhh the biggest value in `C` is tm

Comment: @beginner array are 0 indexed so the values in C must be in the `[0 ; tm -1 ]` range

Comment: @John3136 debugged part is in the update

Comment: @dvhh yes, the dimension of the matrix is as you point it out.

Comment: @beginner @John3136 this is the compiler output, not a debugger run, try using `gdb` for debugging, or maybe `valgrind` could help you point the problem in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80717/discussion-between-dvhh-and-beginner).

Comment: I do not intend to download.

Comment: you must learn how to use a debugger when you intend to do any programming. One may not ask questions that ask for debugging help here on SO. also don't expect others to read your trillion lines of code and debug it for you. narrow it down to a minimum that produces the same results.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you were right, the issue is related with the `stoi`, I have updated the post with the respective debugged part obtained with `g++ -g file`. Would you, please, help me some seconds more?

Comment: @John3136  I have updated the post with the respective debugged part obtained with `g++ -g file` and the issued part is with `stoi` Would you, please, help me some seconds more?

Comment: @dvhh I have updated the post with the respective debugged part obtained with `g++ -g file` and the issued part is with `stoi`. Would you, please, help me some seconds more?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You told us a lot of stuff, but left us guessing as to what you wanted us to help you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you would need to add check on your externally accepted values (using `assert` might be a start) Like :

- checking `tm>0`
- `ler>0`
- `C[i]<tm`
- `A[i]!=NULL`
- `B[i]!=NULL`

As mentionned in the comment it an **off by one** issue :

in LER the values **should be from 0 to tm-1**
or use `B[i][j]=C[k]-1;` at line 88

Comment: I wanted to add, that either using `gdb` or cutting your input into pieces would have helped you pinpointed the problem