# segmentation fault issue # n

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, coredump

Is this command line wrong? `FILE *TM = fopen("TM","r");`

When I compile my code with: `g++ -O3 -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7 -std=c++11 prueba3.cpp -o prueba3 -lstdc++` or `g++ -O3 -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7 -std=c++0x prueba3.cpp -o prueba3 -lstdc++` and then run the executable, I got:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

When I debug the code with dbg I got the following result:

```
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400e59: file prueba3.cpp, line 10.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/alejo/Desktop/CM/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at prueba3.cpp:10
10  {
(gdb) s
19      FILE *TM = fopen("TM","r");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
2053    2618
2618    3223
3223    3431

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040138e in main () at prueba3.cpp:98
98          A[b][a]=A[b][a]+1;
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 3977] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

But, still, I don't understand how to apply it on my code, which is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a,b,i,j,div,tm,ler;  
char string0[256],string1[256],string2[256];
/////////// 
//                          Load files:
//                          TM = size of the sqaure matrix
//                          REL = List of numbers
//                          LER = How many numbers are in REL
/////////// 
FILE *TM = fopen("TM","r");
if(TM == NULL)
{  
    printf("Can't open %s\n","TM");
    exit(1);
}
fscanf(TM,"%255s",string2);
tm = std::stoi(string2);
fclose(TM);

FILE *REL = fopen("REL","r");
if(REL == NULL)
{  
    printf("Can't open %s\n","REL");
    exit(1);
}

FILE *LER = fopen("LER","r");
if(LER == NULL)
{  
    printf("Can't open %s\n","LER");
    exit(1);
}
fscanf(LER,"%255s",string1);
ler = std::stoi(string1);
fclose(LER);

div=ler/2;
///////////     
//                          Allocate matrices
///////////     
int **A;
A = (int **)malloc(tm*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<tm;i++)
{
    A[i]=(int*)malloc(tm*sizeof(int));
}

int *B;
B = (int*) malloc(ler*sizeof(int));
///////////     
//                          Set zero all elementes of allocated matrices
///////////     
if( A != NULL )
{
    for(i=0;i<tm;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<tm;j++)
        {
            A[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

if( B != NULL )
{
    for(i=0;i<ler;i++)
    {
        B[i]=0;
    }
}
/////////// 
//                          Put the LER numbers of REL in B[i] 
//                          with converting number-string to number-int
///////////     
for(i=0;i<ler;i++)
{
    fscanf(REL,"%255s",string0);
    B[i]=std::stoi(string0);
}
fclose(REL);
/////////// 
//                          Reocate numbers of C[i] in A[i][j]
/////////// 
for(i=0;i<div;i+=2)
{
    a=B[i]-1;
    b=B[i+1]-1;
    std::cout<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\n";
    A[b][a]=A[b][a]+1;
    A[a][b]=A[a][b]+1;
}   
free(B);
/////////// 
//                          Print A[][]
/////////// 
for(i=0;i<tm;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<tm;j++)
    {
        cout<<A[i][j]; 
    }
    cout<<"\n"; 
}
free(A);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just in case, the files are:

```
REL:

2054
2619
2619
3224
3224
3432
194
2619
2619
3224
3224
3432
448

LER

30846

TM

3434
```

Comment: @BartoszKP would you show me how it would be all in C++? pelase

Comment: You need to watch/print the values of `a` and `b` to make sure they are what you think they are.  I have a feeling that they are not within the range of the array, this causing the crash.  Print those values will show exactly where `A[b][a]` or `A[a][b]` are actually looking and writing into memory.

Comment: I have already just check it and the values of REL are below `tm` if you agree, please see the update, I put a small working file

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, Yes, you were right, the values are over `tm`. Silly of me.

Comment: You've already found the problem, but... Why did you even suspect the `fopen`? Gdb clearly told you the problem was with `A[b][a]=A[b][a]+1;`. `fopen` can't lead to segmentation faults (and it doesn't throw exceptions either); if it fails to open the file, it will simply return a NULL pointer.

Comment: @FabioTurati Last time of programming on C or similar was 5 years ago. I have returned and until now I have remembering for 2 days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Another coredump issue in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880655/another-coredump-issue-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've indicated yourself, the size of `A` (`tm`) is 3371 x 3371. The file REL.txt contains numbers like `3383` (line 138 in the file) which are larger than the dimensions of `A`. This makes you reach out of bounds in this part, as indicated by the debugger:

```
for(i=0;i<div;i+=2)
{
    a=B[i]-1;
    b=B[i+1]-1;
    std::cout<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\n";
    A[b][a]=A[b][a]+1;           // b or a may be larger than 3371
    A[a][b]=A[a][b]+1;
}
```

You don't need to verify this manually though, you can implement it:

```
for(i=0;i<div;i+=2)
{
    a=B[i]-1;
    b=B[i+1]-1;
    std::cout<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\n";

    if (a >= tm || b >= tm)
    {
        std::cerr << "Out of bounds!" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }

    A[b][a]=A[b][a]+1;           // b or a may be larger than 3371
    A[a][b]=A[a][b]+1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, the values are over `tm`. Silly of me.

Answer (score -1):

```
int *B;
B = (int*) malloc(ler*sizeof(int));

...

if( B != NULL )
{
    for(i=0;i<tm;i++)
    {
        B[i]=0;
    }
}
```

This is a catastrophe if `tm > ler`.

Also, why do you condition this code in `B` being valid, but then unconditionally re-assign values to every element of `B`? Neither of those things makes sense. If you're going to re-assign values to every element, why zero them? And if you're going to access the array without checking its validity later, why check its validity here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, all your suggestion were check and still got the same error